# Does $store.state.x access the same object reference in Vuex when used in different components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I'm following a [tutorial](https://youtu.be/Yg5zkd9nm6w?t=5810) to create an eCommerce website using Vue Router and Vuex. When I do `this.cart = this.$store.state.cart` in different components, the cart variables seem to have the same object reference since the total item count in each component updates whenever it is changed in the other component even though no mutation has been committed (check the [linked/timestamped video](https://youtu.be/Yg5zkd9nm6w?t=5810) for demonstration). Is this the case here? I know that objects are passed by reference in JS but Vuex stores cannot be changed directly without committing a mutation, which would make it seem like the object is being duplicated in the background whenever the store is accessed.

The two relevant components are a navbar displaying how many items are in the cart, and a more detailed Cart.vue component, both of which use Vuex to access the cart's state by assigning `this.cart = this.$store.state.cart` on the mounted lifecycle hook. The navbar in App.vue looks like this (details omitted):

```
<template>
  <div>
    ... Cart link in navbar
    <span>Cart ({{ cartTotalLength }})</span>
    ...
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      cart: {
        items: []
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.cart = this.$store.state.cart
  },
  computed: {
    cartTotalLength() {
      return this.cart.items.reduce((acc, curVal) => {
        return acc += curVal.quantity
      }, 0)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The Cart.vue component is similar (it also sets an instance variable for cart on the mounted lifecycle hook), though it displays a more detailed view of cart contents and has buttons to change the quantity of items per product (not shown below):

```
<template>
  ... Cart Summary
    {{ cartTotalLength }} items
  ...
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Cart',
  data() {
    return {
      cart: {
        items: []
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.cart = this.$store.state.cart
  },
  computed: {
    cartTotalLength() {
      return this.cart.items.reduce((acc, curVal) => {
        return acc += curVal.quantity
      }, 0)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    incrementQuantity(item) {
      cart.item.quantity += 1
    }
    ...
  }
}
</script>
```

Why does the item count in the navbar get updated when the item count is updated in Cart.vue through the `incrementQuantity` method when no mutation is committed? Does `this.$store.state.cart` reference the same object every time it is used even though in separate components?

Comment: `state.cart` stays the same object everywhere until it's reassigned with another one, `state.cart = {...}`. *Vuex stores cannot be changed directly without committing a mutation, which would make it seem like the object is being duplicated in the background whenever the store is accessed* - this isn't true. Objects aren't duplicated, unless you duplicate them explicitly. Direct state mutation is discouraged but totally possible.

Comment: @EstusFlask when I access`$store.state.cart`, I get a proxy for the actual cart object stored within Vuex, so would it be correct to assume that the same proxy object is being used in both the App.vue and Cart.vue components, leading to the reactivity between the two?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I strongly suggest you configure Vuex using [strict mode](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/strict.html) while developing to avoid directly mutating state

Comment: They could be different proxies (don't pass `===` comparison) but as long as they are proxies to the same object, they efficiently behave as the same object.